# Firefox and Chrome not loading a script from a coldfusion include?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, coldfusion

I've inherited some coldfusion code that generally works fine.

The problem I'm having is on a page that has a cfinclude that refuses to load one particular script. It wouldn't bother me nearly as much if it didn't load the script the line before it, but it does.

Firefox doesn't even attempt to get the script (as far as fiddler can see), and chrome fails to get it as well (unless you have that page open when you open chrome, in which case it works until you refresh the page). Internet Explorer, however, is doing great with this and loading it just fine!

You can see the live page [here](http://carnegielibrary.org/locations/main). The top "ad" on the right should fade out and fade in a new ad every 4 seconds.

This is where the script is called (adrotator.js). the jQuery.js is getting loaded fine, and the `alert` I put in also works just fine (above or below the script that isn't loading):

```
<cfsilent>
    <!--- THIS IS THE LIST OF LARGE ADS FOR IN THE LARGE AD ROTATOR --->
    <cfinclude template="ads/adlist_inc.cfm">
    <!--- PUT IN THE NUMBER OF LARGE ADS HERE --->
    <cfset adListLarge = GetNumAds("large", 0)> <!--- 0 means all the ads --->
</cfsilent>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/locations/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("test!") <!--- WHY DOES THIS WORK --->
</script>
<!--- WHEN THIS DOESN'T WORK? --->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/locations/js/adrotator.js"></script>

<div id="spotlight_ad_top">
<cfoutput><cfset temp = MakeAllAdImgTags(adListLarge)>#temp#</cfoutput>
</div>
```

This page is called in by this:

```
<!-- TOP SPOTLIGHT GRAPHICS IN RIGHT COLUMN -->
<div id="locations-branchleaf-spotlight">
<!--- THIS PULLS THE LOCATION SPECIFIC AD IMAGE IF THERE IS ONE  --->
<cfoutput query="ReturnLocationInfo">
        <cfinclude template="../#initials#/spotlightcontent_inc.cfm">
</cfoutput>
<!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE LOCATION-WIDE PROMOTIONAL SPOTLIGHT -->
<cfinclude template="/locations/includes/spotlightcontent_inc.cfm">
</div>
```

Which in turn is called by this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<!--- THIS IS THE INCLUDED PAGE FOR EACH LOCATION'S HOME PAGE INDEX.CFM --->
<cfset PAGE_TITLE = ReturnLocationInfo.name & " - Carnegie Library of Pittsburgh">
<title><cfoutput>#PAGE_TITLE#</cfoutput></title>
<cfinclude template="/includes/header-locations-branchleaf_inc.html">
<cfinclude template="../breadcrumb_inc.html">

<div id="content">
<!-- THIS BRANCH/DEPARTMENT'S NAME, DUMP THE DASH IF IT IS THE pop-up -->
<h1><cfif locationID is 92><cfelse>CLP &ndash; </cfif><cfoutput>#ReturnLocationInfo.name#</cfoutput></h1>
<!-- BRANCH LEAF - LEFT COLUMN: LOCATION PHOTO & CONTACT INFO, HOURS EVENTS, LINKS  -->
<div id="leftcolumn">
<!-- 1: LOCATION'S PHOTO/CONTACT INFO WITH LINKSTO DIRECTIONS AND CONTACT FORM -->
<cfinclude template="information_inc.cfm">

<!-- 2: LOCATION'S EMERGENCY NOTICE PULLED FROM TAB MGR NOTICES (SPOTLIGHTS) -->
<cfinclude template="notice_inc.cfm">

<!-- 3: LOCATION'S HOURS GRID -->
<cfinclude template="hours_inc.cfm">

<!-- Testing out location specific notifications! -->
<cfinclude template="notification_inc.cfm">

<!-- 4: LOCATION'S EVENTS -->
<!--- IF THIS IS THE PCCENTER (13) OR JCEC (6), INCLUDE THE programs_inc.cfm IN /locations/pccenter/ --->
<cfif locationID IS 13 or locationID IS 6>
    <cfinclude template="/locations/pccenter/programs_inc.cfm"> 
<cfelse>
    <cfinclude template="programs_inc.cfm">
</cfif>

<!-- 5: LINKS FOR LOCATION -->
<cfinclude template="links_inc.cfm">

<!-- 6: STAFF PICK FOR LOCATION IF ONE EXISTS-->
<cfinclude template="staffpick_inc.cfm">
  </div> <!--//end leftcolumn -->

  <!-- BRANCH LEAF - RIGHT COLUMN: SPOTLIGHT, FLICKR PHOTO GALLERY -->
  <div id="rightcolumn">
<!--- LOCATION'S UNUSED MAP AND DIRECTIONS
<cfinclude template="directions_inc.cfm">  --->
<!-- 9. THE SPOTLIGHT AD - FORMERLY TOPAD -->
<cfinclude template="spotlight_inc.cfm">

<!-- 10: PHOTOS TAGGED WITH THIS BRANCH IN FLICKR -->
<cfinclude template="gallery_inc.cfm">
  </div> <!--//end rightcolumn -->
</div> <!--//end content -->
<cfinclude template="/includes/footer_inc.html">
```

Is there something I'm missing why it won't load the script? If I load the script in a new tab, it connects and displays it just fine.

Here's the script:

```
var activeAdNum = 0;
var totAds = 0;
var adSpeed = 4*1000;
var userBusy = false;

rotate_ads = function() {
  if (userBusy){
    window.setTimeout(rotate_ads, adSpeed);
    return;
  }
  jQuery(function(){
    nextAdNum = (activeAdNum % totAds) + 1;
    $("#rotating_ad_"+activeAdNum).fadeOut(500, function(){ 
      $("#rotating_ad_"+activeAdNum).removeClass("rotating_ad_active").addClass("rotating_ad_inactive");
      $("#rotating_ad_"+nextAdNum).fadeIn("slow", function(){
        $("#rotating_ad_"+nextAdNum).removeClass("rotating_ad_inactive").addClass("rotating_ad_active");
        activeAdNum = nextAdNum;
      });
    });
  });
  window.setTimeout(rotate_ads, adSpeed);     
}

jQuery().ready(function() { 
  $(".rotating_ad").hover(
    function(){
      userBusy = true;
    },
    function(){
      userBusy = false;
    }
  );
  var adCount = 0;
  $(".rotating_ad").each(function(){adCount++;});
  totAds = adCount;
  if (totAds > 0){
    activeAdNum = 1;
  }

  window.setTimeout(rotate_ads, adSpeed);
});
```

Comment: Did you look at the generated HTML and see if the script is there?  If not then you may have a condition that is causing it to not be included.

Comment: It's in the HTML. Loading in safemode has it working in firefox, time to go through my extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OH GOD, I FEEL STUPID.

because it has the word "ad" in it, adblock plus totally stops it from working (regardless of the fact that it is just events at the branch). I'm going to try renaming the script.

Oh man, I can't believe it was that easy. I spent the better part of yesterday trying to figure this out.

FUTURE WARNING: Unless it's actually advertisements, don't call your script `.*ad.*` anything, because ABP will see it and destroy it on sight.

Comment: Always disable AdBlock for local development and production project sites. :)

Comment: If I had I probably wouldn't have noticed that it wasn't working!